# Is there a way to detect if an excel file was generated on windows or mac using PHPExcel?

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm using PHPExcel to generate a xls template that the user can download and fill it with the data he wants.
As we know, excel saves the date in a numeric format. I'm using this function to convert the data and return the timestamp:

```
public static function excelToTimestamp($excelDateTime, $isMacExcel=false) {
    $myExcelBaseDate = $isMacExcel ? 24107 : 25569; // 1st jan 1904 or 1st jan 1900
    if (!$isMacExcel && $excelDateTime < 60) {
        //  Adjust for the spurious 29-Feb-1900 (Day 60)
        --$myExcelBaseDate;
    }
    // Perform conversion
    if ($excelDateTime >= 1) {
        $timestampDays = $excelDateTime - $myExcelBaseDate;
        $timestamp = round($timestampDays * 86400);
        if (($timestamp <= PHP_INT_MAX) && ($timestamp >= -PHP_INT_MAX)) {
            $timestamp = intval($timestamp);
        }
    } else {
        $hours = round($excelDateTime * 24);
        $mins = round($excelDateTime * 1440) - round($hours * 60);
        $secs = round($excelDateTime * 86400) - round($hours * 3600) - round($mins * 60);
        $timestamp = (integer) gmmktime($hours, $mins, $secs);
    }
    return $timestamp;
}
```

The problem is that I have to detect if the file that the user imported to the system was filled using excel for mac or windows, so that I can set the date correctly (mac uses 1904 calendar, while windows uses 1900).

**I'd like to know if is there a way to detect it using PHPExcel. If not, I may let the user informs it with a radiobutton, maybe...**

Comment: Out of interest (before I answer) is there any particular reason why you're writing your own date conversion functions when these are already built into PHPExcel?

Comment: it's because I set readonlydata as true... in the documentation, it's being said: "It is important to note that Workbooks (and PHPExcel) store dates and times as simple numeric values: they can only be distinguished from other numeric values by the format mask that is applied to that cell. When setting read data only to true, PHPExcel doesn't read the cell format masks, so it is not possible to differentiate between dates/times and numbers." and it's only supported for gnumeric, right?

Comment: in fact.. It's not mandatory for me to use this method (readonlydata)... Can it be done in a more simple way?

Comment: You can still use the built-in date conversion methods to convert an Excel timestamp to a PHP timestamp, even with readonlydata true. What you can't do is automatically detect whether a cell is formatted as a date or not. The PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP() method will still work correctly, and will still detect whether Windows 1900 or Mac 1904 calendar was being used

Comment: Yes, it should work for time as well

Comment: @MarkBaker, I just notice that using this method, the date is one day late. in the excel file it is written: 08/28/2012, and after doing the code, it is written: 08/27/2012. Isn't this problem because of the macXwindows calendar?

Comment: That's because the date-handling methods assume that any PHP dates are UST: any PHP dates passed to convert to Excel should be UST (e.g. generated by gmmktime or equivalent) and any value returned from a PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP() call will be UST

Comment: just solved it using the other function u have in PHPExcel library: PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHPObject

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just solved this problem using, as @markBaker suggested, the PHPExcel function to convert the date and time, doing this:

```
 foreach ($rowLine as $header => $col) {
        if ($header == self::COLUMN_DATE) {
            //transform the excel date value into a datetime object
            $date = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHPObject($sheetData[$row][$col]);
            $rowLine[$header] = $date->format('m/d/Y');
        }else if ($header == self::COLUMN_HOUR) {
            //transform the excel time value into a datetime object
            $time = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHPObject($sheetData[$row][$col]);
            $rowLine[$header] = $time->format('H:i');
        }else{
            $rowLine[$header] = $sheetData[$row][$col];
        }
 }
```

Comment: Use this for PhpSpreadsheet: `$dateTime = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date::excelToDateTimeObject($dateValue);`