# Mismatch when converting Excel date numbers to Unix Timestamp using PHP

Tags: php, date, timezone, phpexcel

Hi~ I am using **PHPExcel 1.7.7** to read XLSX files and present the results in web pages.

I'm trying to get the value of a cell that stores a date & time string and process it in PHP using the following code.

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Canberra'); 

$value = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A1')->getValue();

define('MIN_DATES_DIFF', 25569);
define('SEC_IN_DAY', 86400);

function excel2Timestamp($excelDate)
{
  if($excelDate <= MIN_DATES_DIFF)  
  {
     return 0;
  }

  return ($excelDate - MIN_DATES_DIFF) * SEC_IN_DAY;
}

echo $result = date('H:i:s d/m/Y', excel2Timestamp($value)); 

?>
```

while the original value in the cell is "00:00:00 01/07/2012", instead of giving me the correct results, the output from the above PHP code shows "10:00:00 01/07/2012".

It seems that it is caused by the time zone differences, but I have already defined the time zone at the beginning of the code. No idea what is wrong with it.

Can anyone please help me with it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: First question... why aren't you using PHPExcel's built-in conversion functions to translate the Excel timestamp value to a unix timetsamp or to a PHP DateTime object? It seems to be a week where I see people insisting on writing their own. Secondly, the Excel timestamp doesn't have a timezone applied: it is a UST value: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/issues/38

Comment: Take a look at my answer here: 
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12246116/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-an-excel-file-was-generated-on-windows-or-mac-using

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Forget your function to convert to timestamp (I was doing the same too)... PHPExcel does the convertion automatically, so try doing this:

```
//get the excel date value (if it's stored in the A1 cell)
$excelDate = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A1')->getValue();
//converts from excel format to a datetime object
$date = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHPObject($excelDate);
//format the date as you want.
$formatedDate = $date->format('m/d/Y');
```

It should work.